# Unable to run a Subclipsed Groovy script in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, run-configuration

After installing the Groovy plug-in in Eclipse, clicking Run brought up a list: Groovy Console - Groovy Script - Java Application. I'd select **Groovy Script** and it would take off.

Now, after checking out a colleague's Groovy project with Subclipse, opening a script in it, clicking **Run** brings up "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches".

Selecting **Run As...** shows '(none applicable)'. So I select **Run Configurations...** and click **Groovy Script**, but the **Run** button stays dimmed. Eclipse evidently needs more info, but what?

Comment: I should add that when I add a new configuration, the project doesn't appear undeer Browse. If I manually enter the project and class names, Run says "non-existing project".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your colleague didn't check in the .project file. It contains the "nature" that defines the project as being a Groovy project. I don't know for certain but it is not uncommon for eclipse actions to be predicated on the presence of an appropriate nature.

I would also check the .classpath is present and valid as it should contain the Groovy libraries required to compile and run your script.

Assuming they are missing, get your colleague to add them, and after syncing you should be good to go.

Comment: Your mention of classpath led three of us to the answer. The Oracle jar file needed by the project was added as a local jar file, so the path in the .classpath file was absolute, using the path on the system that last checked it in. After creating a 'lib' folder in the project, dragging-and-dropping the jar file into it, and adding the jar to the classpath via Eclipse, the programs could be run. Thank you, Michael.